# Can I access to iframe 's parent's element from the iframe page

Tags: iframe, element, parent

First the two page in under the same domain

In the parent page.htm I have only a element like `input#test`,

then I set a iframe in the parent page,called child.htm,in the child.html I write js to find the parent input element,like

```
var parent = window.self.top;
```

but I can't use `var input = $(parent).find('input#test')` to find the input element in parent.htm

Can I access to it? How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var input = $(window.self.top).contents().find('input#test');
```

or

```
var input = $(window.self.top.document).find('input#test');
```

Comment: I removed `parent` from the first answer. It is probably not a good idea to declare a variable called `parent` as this is a global variable.