# DOM Get Element Outside the HTML Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I have some big problem please kindly help me..

I have a html structure like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="getInHere">Get me</div>
<iframe>
<html>
<head>

$('#clickme').click(function(){
  // i don't what should be put here to get to #getInHere div
});

</head>
<body>

<a href="#" id="clickme">Click me</a>
</body>
</html>
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

I must append something on the `#getInHere` and I don't know how. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: From within your iframe, you want to access the iframe's parent elements. See this answer to simliar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792401/can-i-access-to-iframe-s-parents-element-from-the-iframe-page

Answer (score -1):

**jQuery:**

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
    $('#getInHere').append('text');
});
```

**jsFiddle Live Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/P89sa/